# How do I find out if a component is compatible with the current version of Spring

Tags: spring, maven, pom.xml, dependency-management

For a given spring version how do I find out which if the latest version of a component is supported or not,For example-if we are using  spring boot (v1.5.8.RELEASE) ,how do I know if that spring version supports the  latest version of a component say netty-all  (4.1.63.Final) or the spring boot version does not support it and needs a spring version upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I guess you put the version into your POM and run your tests. Then you'll see.

Comment: Isn't there any other way? Any page where there is a list of supported versions for that spring version.

Comment: Hey I found this page- [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.22.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html) but what I understood is ,it just tells you the version that would be added by default you don't specify any version ,correct me if I'm wrong